# How is compression ratio related to number of dct coefficients

Tags: image-processing, dct, compression

Lets say we have a picture with 6bits/pixel and we use discrete cosine transform with 8x8 blocks of pixels and each coefficient is 8 bits. We can use 2 8x8 masks, a zonal mask A and a zonal bit allocation mask B.

A =

```
[1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 ...... ]
```

B =

```
[8 7 6 4 3 2 1 0
 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
 6 5 4 3 3 1 1 0
 4 4 3 3 2 1 0 0
 3 3 3 2 1 1 0 0
 2 2 1 1 1 0 0 0
 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  ]
```

Is it correct to say that for A we have 64 : 15 compression namely 4.2 : 1 cause we keep 15 coefficients out of 64? does the same apply for B ?

Comment: your original image is 6 bits but not 8 bits?

Comment: yeah its 6bits. if it was 8 bits then if would be like i said above. thanks btw.

Comment: you are very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compression ratio is defined as the amount of bits in the original image divided by the amount of bits in the compressed image. In the original image the number of coefficients is `64`, while you choose `15` coefficients after DCT in the compressed image with mask `A`. The ratio is `64*6/15*8`. With mask `B` it is `64*6/41*8`